# How do I refresh a bound GridView after the ObservableCollection<T> has be sorted?

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml

The implementation is a for a Refresh button. I use .Clear() to empty the list, then add back in the latest data. After the data is loaded I use the following function to then sort the list:

```
public void SortByDate()
    {
        this.oCol = new ObservableCollection<OCol>(this.oCol.OrderByDescending(myDate => myDate));
    }
```

The GridView refreshes with the information that I add into it, but when I run the SortByDate() function, the GridView does not refresh to reflect the new order. What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to raise a `PropertyChanged` event for the property that is backed by `oCol`. You have changed the collection and the framework is still databinding to the old collection.